# How do I loop through WindowBuider JPanels in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, loops, windowbuilder

I've made a 1v1 text-based fighter with the following three panels:

- Intro
- Character Customization
- Fight

After you finish the fight I want to loop back to the 2nd panel because you receive XP to unlock more characters and weapons. I tried just placing a do while loop for the last two panels in the Initialization method but the program wont run.

PS this is a Java Application.

Comment: One of the better ways to do it would be to use a `CardLayout`, see [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for more details

Comment: I am using a card layout for the panels!

Comment: Im stupid, I didnt think of just setting the 2nd panel to visible and the last one to not visible...